# Limpar dados da variavel da memoria

Tags: php, jquery

Tenho uma função que através da detecção do click faz um post para act.php
o act chama uma função php que insere os comentários.

Tudo funciona, massssssssssss, como não tem refresh na página e a intenção é essa mesmo, quando vou inserir um segundo comentário o código é executado, 1 + 2 vezes, se for inserir um terceiro, é executado 1 + 3 vezes, tem como "limpar da memória" os dados já enviados, pois está executando várias vezes o mesmo código, só para se der refresh na página.

jQuery:

```js
$("#btnanotacao").click(function() {
    d = new Date;
    idcli = $("#idclientecoment").val();
    anot = $("#fanotacao").val();
    dat = d.getFullYear() + '-' + d.getMonth() + '-' + d.getDate();
    jQuery.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: "lib/act.php",
        data: {
            acao: 'coment',
            idclie: idcli,
            anotacao: anot,
            dt: dat
        },
        success: function(data) {
            var a;
            a = parseInt(data);
            if (a != 1) {
                alert(data);
            } else {
                alert("Comentario Inseridos com Sucesso");
            }
        }
    })
    return false;
});
```

HTML:

```html
<textarea class="form-control" id="fanotacao" rows="6" placeholder="Digite aqui alguma anotação que julgar útil."></textarea>
<input type="hidden" id="idclientecoment" value="<?php echo $id; ?>">
<button type="button" id="btnanotacao" class="btn btn-primary btn-block mt-sm">Save</button>
```

PHP:

```
if(isset($_POST['acao']) && $_POST['acao']== 'coment'){
$comentarios        = array(
    'idcli'             => $idclie,
    'data'              => $dt,
    'comentario'        => $anotacao
);
$query = DBCreate('comentarios', $comentarios);
    if($query)
        echo "1";
    else{
        echo "0";
    }
}
```

Comment: Acho que pode ser por causa de `anot = $("#fanotacao").val();` que está a importar e enviar para o PHP com os comments que já tinha. Porque achas que o código é executado mais do que uma vez?

Comment: Não fica claro isso no código que você postou, mas pela descrição do problema, parece que você esta adicionando o evento "click" novamente, toda vez que o evento dispara. Se for esse o caso, você pode usar: http://api.jquery.com/unbind/, antes de "agendar" novo evento. Ou rever seu código, de forma que o evento seja definido uma única vez, caso isso seja possível. Verifique se o número de "vezes" que o código é executando, corresponde ao número de requisições enviadas, ou bota um "alert/console.info" dentro do evento click, e verifique se o problema está mesmo no JavaScript.

Comment: Sim, no evento click mesmo, já coloquei o alert, informa 5 vezes a msg. não dá pra entender, pois não há loop de repetição, apenas cria o array, da post com o jquery, o php recebe, manda inserir no bd, dá o resultado 1 e o alert é disparado, vou tentar o unbind aki, tenho várias funções idênticas porém com form.

Comment: É, infelizmente não deu, esse script continua guardando na memória os dados enviados na primeira vez e fazendo vários posts...

Comment: Descobri o motivo desse bendito erro, estava chamando o arquivo com as funções js duas vezes, no arq perfil.php quando comentava e no documento anotacao.php que era chamado no .load. Odeio agarrar nessas coisinhas...